# Need help running Hello World in intelliJ IDEA IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

I've installed intelliJ idea and am trying to run hello world, but I keep getting a popup for edit configurations. I have no idea what to do next. I had this installed on another computer and it was running properly. I've attached screenshots of my workspace

[My workspace image attachment, click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fz7N.png)

I'm getting the following error when I try to run HelloWorld.java, I don't know what this means, screenshot attached

[Error when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeiVr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a Run configuration using that Edit Configurations popup.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-application.html

As for your runtime error, I can't tell from here but I'd start with putting your source files under the `src/` folder.

Comment: It's weird when I have a HelloWorld.java file it's not running, when I refactor and rename the file to HelloWorld2.java, everything is working fine. 

Do you know why this is happening?